# Stop showing row after clicking on URL. PHP MYSQLI

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a website where users can post links and interact with them.

All users are shown a table with all the links of the users.

But I need to ask a question, for when a user interacts with a link, that link will not be shown again.
That is, when a user clicks on a link, the link disappears only for the user who clicked

I have done the following.

I have the table (users) where all the users are stored.

```
Table1 (users):
----------------
| id | username |
----------------
|  1 |  user1   |
----------------
|  2 |  user2   |
----------------
|  3 |  user3   |
----------------
```

This is the second table where all the links are stored

```
Table2 (links):
----------------
| id | urls |
----------------
|  1 |  url1   |
----------------
|  2 |  url2   |
----------------
|  3 |  url3   |
----------------
```

Now suppose that (USER2 of table 1 (users)) clicked on the following links (URL1 and URL2 of table2 (links)).

When the user clicks on an url, the following values are stored in a third table as follows:

```
Table3 (blockuser):
-----------------------
| id | idLinks | users |
-----------------------
|  1 |    1    | user2 |
------------------------
|  2 |    2    | user2 |
-----------------------
```

Now I would like the table that contains all the links to be shown to each user in the following way.
This is what I want to achieve:

```
        User1:                    User2:                   User3:
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
| TABLE: ALL LINKS |      | TABLE: ALL LINKS |     | TABLE: ALL LINKS |
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  ID   |  URLS    |      |  ID   |  URLS    |     |  ID   |  URLS    |
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  1    |  url1    |      |  3    |  url3    |     |  1    |  url1    | 
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  2    |  url2    |                               |  1    |  url2    |
--------------------                               --------------------
|  3    |  url3    |                               |  1    |  url3    |
--------------------                               --------------------
```

And this is what I have been able to achieve.

```
        User1:                    User2:                   User3:
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
| TABLE: ALL LINKS |      | TABLE: ALL LINKS |     | TABLE: ALL LINKS |
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  ID   |  URLS    |      |  ID   |  URLS    |     |  ID   |  URLS    |
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
|  3    |  url3    |      |  3    |  url3    |     |  3    |  url3    | 
--------------------      --------------------     --------------------
```

That is, when a user clicks on a link, the link is no longer displayed for all users.

But what I want to achieve is that when a user clicks on a link, the link will stop showing, only for the user who clicked on the link.....

This is the code I have to show the table:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    links
LEFT JOIN
    blockuser ON blockuser.idLinks = links.id
WHERE
    blockuser.idLinks IS NULL
```

Comment: you would need to add another column and add another clause while keeping track with a boolean value with an INSERT/UPDATE and possibly use sessions as an extra. Add a conditional statement in a loop, then checking if it's equal to 0/1.

Comment: in which table should I add the Boolean field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you 'HAVE TO' use the SQL to show the table?

> ```
> SELECT
>     *
> FROM
>     links
> LEFT JOIN
>     blockuser ON blockuser.idLinks = links.id
> WHERE
>     blockuser.idLinks IS NULL
> ```

Basically use subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE id NOT IN
      (SELECT idLinks FROM blockuser WHERE idUsers = 2)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE id NOT IN
      (SELECT idLinks FROM blockuser WHERE users = 'user2')
```

[User1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2cJ3.png)

[User2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHyz8.png)

[User3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUmOH.png)

Comment: That is the only way to show a table.
I tried what you suggested, but it did not work. Nothing happens

Comment: What does it mean? 'Nothing happens'?

Comment: When I execute what you suggested, all the links were shown. In a nutshell, nothing happened when you executed what you suggested.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: A little bit weird. I tested the query on same database like you have and you can see results on my screenshots.

Comment: I have reviewed and if it works. You do not know how grateful I am. Thank you very much
I already had 3 days trying to do this and looking for suggestions and nobody could give me the answer.
Thank you. you're the best.